# How can I get a single string out of the Dictionary? C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, casting

I've some problems using the Dictionary. How can I get the value back from the Dictionary

I have stored some data in the Dictionary

```
Dictionary<UserSettings.Languages, string> objectiveLanguages
    = new Dictionary<UserSettings.Languages, string>();

objectiveLanguages.Add(UserSettings.Languages.English, objectiveNameEnglish);
objectiveLanguages.Add(UserSettings.Languages.German, objectiveNameGerman);
```

Could someone explain me, how to retreive the stored value again?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do here - what does `GetSFSObject` have to do with anything? What does your `Name` property not do that you want it to?

Comment: You don't typically look for _values_ in a dictionary - you have a _key_ value and get the value associated _with that key_.  Otherwise you just loop through the values until you find a match, which is no better than using a plain list.  If you have the key value it's just `objectiveLanguages[key];`

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `Dictionary` to see how it should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. You know that the value will be present.

   ```
   string str = objectiveLanguages[UserSettings.Languages.English];
   return str;
   ```
2. You don't know that the value will be present, or you'd like to throw your own exception.

   ```
   string str;
   if(objectiveLanguages.TryGet(UserSettings.Languages.English, out str))
       return str;
   else
       throw new ArgumentException(); // or return null, or whatever.
   ```

The choice between these depends on circumstances. Since you're dealing with an enum (or equivalent), the first should probably suffice. If the user was, say, entering data, on the other hand, I'd probably go with the second. It's a similar decision to that of using `int.Parse` versus `int.TryParse`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("For key UserSettings.Languages.English, value = {0}.",
    objectiveLanguages[UserSettings.Languages.English]);

/* returns the value of this key, if present.
 */
```

Ref the MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<UserSettings.Languages, string> objectiveLanguages
    = new Dictionary<UserSettings.Languages, string>();

objectiveLanguages.Add(UserSettings.Languages.English, objectiveNameEnglish);
objectiveLanguages.Add(UserSettings.Languages.German, objectiveNameGerman);

// get some value out of the dict
string dictContent = objectiveLanguages[UserSettings.Languages.English];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets with a key inside.  For example:

```
// returns objectiveNameEnglish
var retrievedValue = objectiveLanguages[UserSettings.Languages.English];
```

For every pair you add, the first item is the key and the second item is the value mapped to it.  MSDN has good examples https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx